# how to mouseMove on an element in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am newbie in protractor, I wrote a code to perform mouseMove on an element but it wasn't working.

```
commonsMethod.findElementDriver(that.gearbox).then(function(foundElement){
    browser.driver.actions().mouseMove(foundElement,{x:0,y:0}).perform();
});
```

Comment: Could you be more specific how it does not work? What is your expected behaviour and what do you observe instead? Thanks.

Comment: Please let us know what kind of error you're seeing and if I were you I would first make sure your element is visible before calling this action (example: foundElement.isDisplayed)

Comment: Actually the scenario is like - the element is not visible at first , it get visible when I hover over on text which is aside it. And then that element is going to visible on which i want to click. I did achieve mouse over on the text and element is visible to me, but my clicking code is not working. When my function (which hovering over text) stop working, then my clicking code is trying to search for the element on which I want to click and that's why it wasn't able to click.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(
    foundElement, newLocationX, 
)
.click()
.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this in the past to successfully mouse to an element and click it:

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(dropdownMenu, {x: 0, y: 0}).perform();
```

Is it possibly adding in the .driver that is the issue here?

Let me know if this works.